# Problems in ADT 10.0.1

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

After Updating to ADT 10.0.1 i am facing some problems like

1. Whenever I click on an item in the
   Eclipse ui builder for android
   (Graphical Layout view) the
   properties view still shows the
   values for the previously selected
   item. The only way to actually
   "select" an item is to click it in
   the outline window.
2. And the short cut key to add a copy
       of item not working too.

Comment: This seems like a bug report, not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's the bug of eclipse 3.6.2. and it's working perfectly in 3.6.1